# In Meteor : How to apply OpenGraph Dynamically for search engines (google+ or Facebook)

Tags: meteor

Actually what I want to do is make my pages link to be shown on the google+ or Facebook post with the OpenGraph tags.

I made my post page changes the

I tried these way,

1. first of all, I declared the meta tag inside  first.
2. then tried to change the tags in the template helpers dynamically like this.

   title: ->
     $("meta[property='og:title']").attr "content", @title
     @title
3. used manuelschoebel:ms-seo package from atmosphere

   onAfterAction: ->
     unless Meteor.isClient then return
     data = @data()
     SEO.set
       title: data.title
       meta:
         description: 'changedBySEO'
       og:
         title: data.title
         description: 'changedBySEO'

But the result alway shows go title in head.
I think google+ or Facebook just grab the meta tags only so the page rendering is not actually working.

Did I miss something or I should apply spiderable packages or something to do this functionality?

Thanks all-

Answer (score 0):

you need the spiderable package, otherwise facebook can't see the tags created by the ms-seo package (remember they're dynamically created in js)